# how I request parameters Alamofire form-data?

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire

I am implementing membership registration. I use alamofire and I must send form-data.. I search about "alamofrie form-data" I success the code but on the server is not upload.. how I do.?

```
func post(_ api: NetworkingAPI) -> DataRequest {
    print(baseURI + api.path)
    print(api.parameters)
    print(api.headers)
    
    return AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        for (key, value) in api.parameters {
            multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
        }
    }, to: baseURI + api.path, method: .post, headers: api.headers).response { resp in
        switch resp.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case .success(_):
            print("success!!")
        }
    }
}
```

parameters is like this.
["password": "", "email": "", "name": ""]

oh is this status code is 500...

Comment: oh is this status code is 500...

Answer (score 0):

500 means "internal server error" - your server side can not properly accept what you are sending.

You can send data using this overload:

```
Alamofire.request(api_url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)
```

where **params** is a dictionary: `typealias Parameters = [String : Any]`

Comment: but I sent like that yesterday but it doesn't work.. so my server team said "reqeust data must be form-data"

Comment: Ask the server team to give you a working example for this API in any other language. Or how the working http request looks like as text..